# Is Psalm 149:4 past, present, future or gnomic?

Tags: israel

Psalm 149:4 asserts:

- the LORD is pleased with his People (ie: the Jews)
- the LORD makes his People an object of admiration by rescuing them

> International Standard Version Psalm 149:4 For the LORD is pleased
>   with his people; he beautifies the afflicted with salvation.

However in the scriptural history of the Jews the LORD is constantly expressing his displeasure with his People and is sending them into slavery, captivity, misery, punishment and expresses his dissatisfaction with them in ways that could largely be described as hatred, frustration and a desire to kill them all off.

So is this referring to a particular time?

- in the past? Perhaps at some ideal time early on?
- the present (from the point of view of the Psalmist) IE: the time of the David's or Solomon's reign?
- the future, during the Messianic, millennial or eschatalogical fulfillment?
- or "gnomic", referring to God's delight whenever they gather and praise him?

Comment: *slavery, captivity, misery, punishment* - Which is probably what David meant by *afflicted* in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am of the opinion that it is yet future. The reason I do is that I see a very important parallel in Isaiah 62:

> NASB Isaiah 62: 4It will no longer be said to you, "Forsaken," Nor to
>   your land will it any longer be said, "Desolate"; But **you will be
>   called, "My delight is in her**," And your land, "Married"; For **the LORD
>   delights in you**, And to Him your land will be married.

Update:

Additionally, Psalm 102 speaks of a "time of her favor":

> NIV Psalm 102:
>   12But you, Lord, sit enthroned forever; your renown endures through
>   all generations.
>   **13You will arise and have compassion on Zion, for it is time to show favor to her; the appointed time has come.** 14For her stones are dear
>   to your servants; her very dust moves them to pity. 15The nations will
>   fear the name of the Lord, all the kings of the earth will revere your
>   glory. **16For the Lord will rebuild Zion and appear in his glory.** 17He
>   will respond to the prayer of the destitute; he will not despise their
>   plea. **18Let this be written for a future generation, that a people not
>   yet created may praise the Lord:** 19“The Lord looked down from his
>   sanctuary on high, from heaven he viewed the earth, 20to hear the
>   groans of the prisoners and release those condemned to death.” 21So
>   the name of the Lord will be declared in Zion and his praise in
>   Jerusalem 22when the peoples and the kingdoms assemble to worship the
>   Lord.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's meant to be in the present because if you look at the context David had just taken the strong-hold of Zion. He had just settled his government so he is saying the Lord the Lord is happy with us doing this and he is creating a song about it.

For more information my source is http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/matthew-henry-complete/psalms/149.html

They know/ It's a fact that it was written in celebration of a won battle of gentiles... If you need another source bible.org/seriespage/psalm-149

Comment: while your answer is somewhat plausible I would appreciate it if you would make it more compelling by showing that that was the occasion, etc. As written it lacks any real authority. Thanks.

Comment: I put my source in if that helps

Comment: Yes, that does help. However, the source does not support your assertion of the context, only saying that "some think..." or something else tentative. So to support your assertion you would need another source. Does that make sense?

Comment: They know/ It's a fact that it was written in celebration of a won battle of gentiles... If you need another source https://bible.org/seriespage/psalm-149 This is not as in depth but it basically says the same thing

Comment: I think that you'll need to better match your assertions to your sources. I think you have the beginning of an answer but if your answer were a baked potato it would still be hard in the middle. Also, the evidence should be present in the answer, not in the comments because the comments will eventually be deleted. Thanks.